# Match-Merge operation for Record Linkage in Oracle Warehouse Builder

Tags: oracle11g, merge, oracle-warehouse-builder

I am new to OWB and performing Match-Merge operation.

**Input data** 
Source(Database) : 22,33,000 records
Target           : 1000 records

**Actual Output**
 20,00,000 records

**Expected Output**
Match-Merge Table: <= 1000 records

I am unable to figure out why i am getting such a huge number in Output of Match-Merge Table which was unexpected.

Please help me by guiding what are all the steps to be followed to reduce the Actual Output to approx. 1000 records.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good starting point for what you are asking for

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/owb/10gr2_owb_extend/matchmerge/matchmerge.htm

Comment: I have tried this approach long back ago... that was when I started the project. Is there any other solutions? Thank you @Philippe

Comment: Have you checked Oracle Data Integrator (ODI) 12c? Since OWB has been discontinued Oracle offers this new product.